# How to calculate escape velocity of timelike particles in Schwarzschild Anti de Sitter spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, energy-conservation, orbital-motion, cosmological-constant, escape-velocity

From the geodesic equations, we can form something like

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\left(\dfrac{d r}{d\tau} \right)^2 +V_{\text{effective}} = \tilde{E}$$

Since $\tilde{E}>0$ will correspond to unbound orbits, can I set $\tilde{E} >0$ and solve for $\dfrac{d r}{d\tau} $ to get the escape velocity for some stationary observer at a coordinate $r$?